# non vectorized to vectorized , matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two issues. Please see followinf code

```
it=0:0.01:360;
jt=0:0.01:270;

LaserS=zeros(size(it,2)*size(jt,2),2);
p=1;
for m=it
    for n=jt
        LaserS(p,:)=[m,n];
        p=p+1;
    end
end
```

It is very slow and also takes a lot of memory (about  7.7765e+009 bytes). So I can't run it. How can i improve it and solve memory issue.
I'm using win7 64 with 8Gb RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do? 'reshape' should solve your problem.

```
LaserS=zeros(size(it,2)*size(jt,2),2);
JT=reshape(repmat(jt,[1,numel(it)]),1,numel(jt)*numel(it));
IT=reshape(repmat(it,[numel(jt),1]),1,numel(jt)*numel(it));

LaserS = [JT.', IT.'];
```

Pre-allocating array is going to save you memory hit. Otherwise there is not memory optimization here.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reduce memory usage unless you use fewer values. Can `it` and `jt` step by 0.1 instead of 0.01?

Here's a way to build your result matrix without a loop.

```
LaserS = [rempat(it.', length(jt), 1), kron(ones(length(it), 1), jt.')];
```

Comment: I was going to say kron should do your job. Nice bit.

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to be doing "nothing" in the sense that, after it runs, you end up with the matrix `LaserS` with a shape of 972000000 x 2. If you really need these values to be loaded to memory at the same time, that is the size and there is not much to do about it.

What would be my first approach, which cannot be inferred directly from the code you posted, is that maybe you can achieve the overall goal of your program if you generate the matrix data "on the fly" while you perform further processing over `LaserS`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
it = it(:);
jt = jt(:);

jt = repmat(jt,size(it,1),1)
it = repmat(it',size(jt,1),1);
it = it(:);

LaserS = [it, jt]
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the nice solutions presented here already, If you want to reduce memory, there's no reason to use `double`. You can use `single` and half the memory required. You can encode the step size `0.01` to a unit step (that is, `it=uint16(0:1:36000)` thus encoding the numbers as integers `uint16`, this will use only one quarter of the memory. etc...

Comment: @ nice suggestion but it is value of angle (degree). I convert it into radian. so it would be difficult to change 1000 lines code to adjust 3600 instead of 360.

Answer (score 0):

Meshgrid will do this cleanly as well, perhaps with a reshape if you insist on having it in an (n*m)-by-2 matrix.  But why do you want that?  It seems like you're actually after something else, and it's possible that bsxfun(,it,jt') would do what you want.